# Resolution on group bounty gaming?

Tags: support, bounties, gaming-the-system, plagiarism

I have recently encountered a very clear case of group bounty gaming.

SO post in question: [Triggering event manually in JS Helper CakePHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11305567/triggering-event-manually-in-js-helper-cakephp/11581276#11581276)

The original posted of the post started the question, did not get a single response for more than 2 weeks, hence offered a +50 bounty, which I believe is legitimate up till this point.

I saw the bounty, answered it on the same day of the bounty. No response from the original poster for 5 days since the answer. I posted a comment 2 days before the bounty ends just to see if he got what he asked answered. No reply from him.

Today the bounty ended. Just mere hours before the bounty ended, a new user popped up with an answer that is too similar to mine, with mere changes in Class and some variable names. Within *minutes*, his answer got accepted.

Did some investigation myself and found out that they were [friends on Facebook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YqsXF.jpg).

I believe it wasn't intended to be a foul play at the start, but once the original poster got his answer, he felt reluctant to give away his +50 reps to someone (in this case, me) who has actually answered his question and got his friend to quickly post a plagiarized answer and immediately marked as resolved.

I flagged it, but I wonder are there anything moderators can do about it besides simply acknowledging it?

Comment: If you've flagged it, there's really no need to call them out here. Handling these cases takes some time because it needs some investigation to see if there really is a problem. And I would personally refrain from [leaving comments like this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11305567/triggering-event-manually-in-js-helper-cakephp/11581276#comment15492214_11681432) but that's perhaps just me.

Comment: @Bart I hesitated leaving that comment actually. It was my bad.

Comment: @Bart: Nah, I'll revert it. It's prolly too big and should have been posted with the moderator attention flag.

Comment: Looks like the bounty you didn't win just got made up for with upvotes.

Comment: Hi @BoltClock'saUnicorn! Indeed, thanks for the upvotes.

Comment: @uzyn: in their defense, the voting fraud ring wanted classes with real names, not just *some* controller ;)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I have passed the issue to Stack Exchange staff who will invalidate the votes. Further action against the involved users might be taken after that happened. Your flag exposed a nice voting ring which will now be blown to pieces.

This can take some time, so i marked your flags as helpful so other mods don't deal with the same case just to notice it's already being handled.

Comment: I have also seen this kind of thing, where a single account getting false voting . that account put bounties very frequently. bounty of 500 many times.

Comment: @ThiefMaster, check both of their profiles, so many serial votes in reputation history

Comment: We already know that. That's why he said "Your flag exposed a nice voting ring"